# CKEditor setData() Not Working with modal form

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have two CKEditor instance on my webpage: the first one is used with other form inputs to add a record to a bootstrap-table; the other is for editing that record in a modal form.

I've tried all different combinations of setData():

**Throws error (with or without callback)**:

```
        var editorModal = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editRemarks', {
            customConfig: '/contest/common/js/ckeditor_config_wf.js'
        });

        editorModal.setData( [row.htmlRemarks], {
            callback: function() {
                this.checkDirty(); // true
            }
        } );
```

**This doesn't throw an error but doesn't set the data**:

```
        editorModal.on( "instanceReady", function( event ){
            editorModal.setData([row.htmlRemarks]);
         });
```

In the latter case, once the modal is shown I can set the contents from the console like this:

```
editorModal.setData('<p>Hello World</p>');
```

Since the table can include up to 10 records, I need to update the modal form inputs dynamically (via an edit button on the table row). What am I doing wrong?

CKEditor v4.15.1 • 09-11-2020

**EDIT**
My main form uses a CKEditor instance to add remarks to an entry, and then clicking the 'Add Model Entry' button adds it to the table below.

[image]

The user can then edit the details by clicking the edit icon and that brings up a modal form:

[image]

My list of plugins from my config file:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'button,dialog,panelbutton,colorbutton,colordialog,wordcount,notification,htmlwriter,confighelper,autogrow';
```

It's only working now as I set the instance on the edit button click:

```
if (CKEDITOR) {
    if (!editorModal) {
        editorModal = CKEDITOR.replace('editRemarks', {
customConfig: '/contest/common/js/ckeditor_config_wf.js'
        });
    }
}
```

... and destroy it on save:

```
if (editorModal) {
    editorModal.destroy();
    editorModal = undefined;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about editor usage context? What plugins / frameworks did you use? If you are able to provide sample code extracted from your project that will be helpful. If it's to complicated any form of video could show what is happening with DOM elements which are involved with editor interaction. It's really hard to determine where is possible bug. Samples code seems to work in isolate case. Could you describe more precisely how your "modal" window behave?

Comment: Also, based on your GH error description (https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues/4468#issuecomment-755059705): there is some plugin involved, but it's hard to say which one. Could you also check this from console stack trace? Providing your editor config would be helpful too.

Comment: Updated details

Comment: Thanks for clarification, it looks quite similar to the existing issue we have -  https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues/4390 (please also check point 3. from https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues/4390#issuecomment-752922198).

Could you check in browser dev tools what is happening with the editor iframe after editor creation, then after modal window shows (is it detached, hidden or removed from DOM)?

See here for example: https://imgur.com/W9MxToJ and https://imgur.com/0NbeQ2P

Answer (score 0):

**This works for CKEditor on modals:**

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {});
editor.on( "instanceReady", function( event ){
   editor.setData('your data');
});
```

Reference:  [setData() method sometimes not displaying the data in the CkEditor](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/14735)

**Another method that works is:**

```
setTimeout(function(){editor.setData(htmlData);},10);
```

Reference: [problems with the setData function](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10663)